# Add a "subpanel" to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am refactoring my code. I have a JPanel:

```
public JPanel createLayout() {
    log.info("create Layout");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add(TestTable());

    return panel;
}
```

I want to add TestTable to this panel. My TestTable looks like that:

```
public void TestTable() {

        JLabel lFxRates = new JLabel("FXRates");

        //get data
        try {
            stm = new SettingsTableModel(settingsService.getTestByParameter("DebtService"));
            stm.setColumnNames(fxColumnNames);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new HelperFunctions().showError("Error loading data!" + e);
        }

        fxTable = new JTable(stm);
        fxTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);

        return null;
    }
```

The problem I am facing is that nothing gets shown, because of `return null`. To which `thing` can I add my table to add it later to my JPanel?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: For better help please post a [Minimal Compilable Runnable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can test out. Hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Also what is `TestTable`. Is it a class? Is that supposed to be the constructor you're showing us? If so, take out the `void`. A constructor should not return anything. Without seeing more code, I'd guess that's the smoking gun, as you haven't mentioned an compile errors.

Comment: @peeskillet Thx for your answer! I generally just want to add the code from the `TestTable()` method to my JPanel. Whats a proper way to achieve that?

Comment: I don't get it though? Do you already have a constructor for `TestTable`? Because you are adding it to the panel, so I'm guessing it's a component class. If you don't already had a constructor defined, then just take out the `void` in the method you're showing us (it will become a constructor), add those component to the class component.

Comment: As an aside, It's just guessing what you're trying to accomplish, without seeing an MCVE. What you're asking makes no sense to me, sorry

Comment: @peeskillet Thx for your answer! The this is I do not know what to return? At the moment I am returning `null`, which displays nothing. Hence, how to return the class properly to the JPanel?

Comment: I hope I'm not the only one, but this sentence _"I generally just want to add the code from the TestTable() method to my JPanel"_ it what really throws me off. It doesn't compute in my brain, with the code you've provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the problem that you are adding nothing, like null.

Everything you add to the panel must inherit from the parent- class called Component.

So, your Class `TestTable`, i hope it is a Class, must inherit from JTable or so.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Can you show me an example how to add it to the `the parent- class called Component.`?

Answer (score 1):

instead of "return null", try adding "return fxTable".

In panel.add(TestTable()), TestTable() is expecting the component.

Comment: Thx! Exactly what I was looking for. What would I do I had also a label in the component. Can`t I just give back the whole component?

Comment: If that is the case , Inside TestTable() , Add the JLabel and JTable inside a new JPanel and return it.